# JS indentation on Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm following the [Douglas Crockford's code convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), but I can't get the correct identation in JS mode in Emacs. I tried to customize the mode, try another mode like js3 but nothing seems to work.

When I have parenthesis and I have to break the expression, Emacs does this:

```
this.offices.each(this.addOfficesToMap,
                  this);
```

When the convention that I'm following that the code should look like:

```
this.offices.each(this.addOfficesToMap,
    this);
```

Any idea of how I can change the indentation on braked expressions?